# Communicate internally between apps on google-app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have 2 app engine services:

1. 1 proxy that acts like a loadbalancer (i need it, i know app engine already have a load balancer)
2. 2 game servers

and a private vpc to access redis (which stores private ips adress and port of all avalaible instances)

I've tried to access the two game servers with the their internal adress from the proxy but i can't (they doesn't respond), and i don't find any usefull information on the internet

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you provide any logs when you try to access them or any other info to troubleshoot the issue like the way you set up the VPC and the connection between them? With the way you phrase the issue, we can only speculate.

Comment: In addition, are you using app engine standard or flex?